# EF CodeFirst: Get all POCO types for DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, poco, dbcontext

Is there any way to get POCO's types from specified DbContext instance?

Comment: having the same issue, did you solve? I need help.. =/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to access the [MetadataWorkspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.metadataworkspace.aspx)

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{

    public void Test()
    {            
        var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;

        var mdw = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace;

        var items = mdw.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.CSpace);
        foreach (var i in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Class Name: {0}", i.Name);
        }
 }
```

Comment: tnx, but I need access to POCO class Type, properties, and properties attributes - EntityType instances returns own implementation in Properties, PropertiesMetadata and etc.

Comment: @DrAlligieri You can get the full name of the type and then use reflections to access properties and attributes.

Comment: FullName returns "CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.TypeNameThere", CodeFirstDatabaseSchema - is wrong namespace for POCO class

Comment: @DrAlligieri Yes. I guess you'd have go through `Assembly.GetTypes()` and match the type with name.

Comment: @Eranga Your above code is quite simple and I like it. You have get all the entity names(string). How to get all the entity Types(Type)? Any way not to use reflection?

Comment: having the same issue, did you solve? I need help.. =/

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, I couldn't edit the accepted answers - you just need to change the dataspace used as follows

```
var items = mdw.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace);
```

to get your POCO classes instead of the EF proxies.

Answer (score 3):

@Lei Yang: you can use this to get all types into a list.

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter) dbContext).ObjectContext;
var mdw = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
var items = mdw.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.CSpace);

var dbContextAssembly = dbContext.GetType().Assembly;

var entityTypes = new List<Type>();
foreach (var i in items) {
    entityTypes.Add(dbContextAssembly.GetType(i.FullName));
}
```

Comment: `i.FullName` does not have the correct namespace, somehow it has the mapping namespace.