# Given a DbContext type what is best way to get a list of all the Entity Types?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
var dbContext = Ioc.Container.GetInstance<MyDbContext>();
        IEnumerable<Type> entityTypes = dbContext.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetProperties()
            .Where(aPropertyInfo => aPropertyInfo.PropertyType.Name.Contains(value: "DbSet"))
            .Select(p => p.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.First());
```

Is what I have done, but is there something cleaner?

Comment: Have you looked at the answer to that question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553639/ef-codefirst-get-all-poco-types-for-dbcontext

Comment: Thank's that works and no magic strings.  I had seen it but for some reason thought it was dated and didn't work on EF6 but I just coded it and it works the same as mine but better code.  Thanks!

Comment: One note.  The MDF way requires you have an instance of the DbContext vs my original way only needs the type.

Comment: Also the second is a collection of EntityType not Type